# Enabling or disabling one monitor in nVidia Twinview on the command line, like with nvidia-settings

Tags: command-line, display-settings, games

For some reasons, most native games as well as Wine have a problem with Twinview. So when starting SC2 I have to manually disable one of my two screens in nvidia-settings. (By going in X Server Display Configuration > click on second monitor > Display > Resolution: off)

I searched hard but couldn't find a way to do that automagically. nvidia-settings itself has non-GUI options (see "nvidia-settings -q all") but none of them seems to do what I want. I want to put that in my startup script for games, which already replaces Compiz with metacity (and back when it exits).

Answer (score 3):

If you're using Twinview the displays are treated as one display with the resolution of all the physical displays put together. You can use [`xrandr`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RandR) to change the current output dimensions, and it will turn on or off the appropriate displays to make it fit.

For example, if you have two 1280x1024 monitors:

```
xrandr --output default --mode 1280x1024   # Just the first monitor
xrandr --output default --mode 2560x1024   # Two 1280 monitors side by side is 2560 wide; this will enable both
```

---

However, this requires that X be configured with both modes. I'm not up on the latest wisdom when it comes to X configuration, but I use this `metamodes` line in my `Screen` section:

```
Option "metamodes" "CRT: 1280x1024_60 +1920+0, DFP: 1920x1200 +0+0; NULL, DFP: 1920x1200"
```

That says "either display on my 1920x1200 DFP at 0x0 and my 1280x1024 CRT to its right, or just display on the DFP and leave the CRT off", so I can tell xrandr to use just the DFP (`--mode 1920x1200`) or both (`--mode 3200x1200`)